# Why does Microsoft's own Sender ID wizard generate a SPF record instead?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, email

I'm trying to create a Sender ID record for [TurboLab.it](http://turbolab.it) with [Microsoft's own Sender ID wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/) but the wizard always return something like `v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:95.141.32.205 -all`: this looks like SPF, not Sender ID to me! Shouldn't it return something like `spf2.0/....`?

Comment: The headline of the wizard states "Sender ID Framework **SPF** Record Wizard" and the next line "This four-step wizard will guide you through the process of creating a new **SPF** record for your DNS domain." In other words, it does what it advertises.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-problem.

Comment: There is a problem. Someone got a Doctorate and can not read titles ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sender ID tries to be backwards compatible and can use `spf1` records.
There is a whole controversy going on around this which I'm not getting into here (see: http://www.openspf.org/SPF_vs_Sender_ID).

In any case, if you choose a scope other than "both" in the wizard it will create `spf2` records.
Otherwise it will only generate a backwards compatible `spf1` record.

Comment: I missed the "both" thing... that was it, thanks!